# Map tables relationship from legacy database w/ entity framework with only primary keys

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, entity-framework-5

**data (table name)**

dataid PK,

value1,

value2,

value3

**data_address (table name)**

dataaddressid PK,

dataid - id to errenddataid,

addressid1 - id to en addressid,

addressid2 - id to en addressid,

type

**address (table namne)**

addressid PK - id to addressid1 or addressid2,

address1,

address2,

name,

zipcode,

city

I have a really hard time trying to map this relations using Entity Framework 5, if some one have an idea or good links I would much appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the database's integrity is sound you could just map the tables and create the associations manually in the EF model.

In a database-first mode I fiddled a bit with a simple data model: Parent + Child without FK. The tables were of course imported without association between them. Then I did "Add Association..." on the Parent, like so:

[image]

Note: no foreign key property yet. I added it manually in the properties of the association:

[image]

[image]

And I could run a linq query on `Parent.Children`.

I think this is the easiest way for you. The edmx design surface gives you some guidance to see which associations you created. You can always add a code generation item to generate a `DbContext` which is easiser to work with than the default `ObjectContext`.