# EntityFramework model-first with a messy database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I would like to recreate a 10 years old application with newer Technologies like ASP.NET WebAPI, AngularJS and the EF. Unfortunately, I have to stick to the existing database as the new webclient will run parallel with the existing one.

The difficulties:
- Some tables are cleared and refilled with data from other systems every week
- Many tables are referencing each other on non-primarykey fields.
- A lot of the Update/Write logic has been done with stored procedures so far.

Because of the first two things I am not able to use navigation properties when I just create an .edmx Diagramm from the existing db model. The only Workaround which came to my mind, is to use views (updatable views) for the tables without primary keys and just add the missing primary key field to the view.

Unfortunately, all changes made to the .edmx file have to redone whenever I update it from the model.

Is there any better solution? Does it even make sense to work with EF when using a database like that? I would probably still like to go this way because I could at least improve my EF knowhow.

Comment: You can add associations in the edmx if they're not in the database (http://stackoverflow.com/q/12581835/861716). These will survive a model update.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. In the given link the principals key field is the ID of the parent. In my case, the two tables are not references over the parents Primary key, but with some kind of "SAP-number" which is not the primary key.

Comment: Too bad, you can only create associations to what EF knows as PK. You *could* tell EF that this "SAP-number" is the PK.