# Entity Framework: Is it possible to model an association without a corresponding foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

We have a database under complete control of dba's who refuse to add any foreign keys to the schema (don't ask).

**I did not create the database schema, nor can I change it.**

So far, we haven't found a way to model associations between entities, because EF refuses to do so without a foreign key in the schema.

Is there any way to bypass or replace Entity Framework's logic for verifying a foreign key exists?  Does the EF architecture allow me to replace/modify this undesirable behavior?  I feel like adding enough logic into repositories to "fake it" would be having to re-implement a significant fraction of EF functionality.

Comment: If you have a column for the foreign key, it should work even if you don't create a foreign key relationship in the database side.

Comment: OK.  How do I get it to disregard the missing foreign key without throwing an exception?  Do you have a working example?

Comment: Are you using database first approach, or code second approach?

Comment: I do ask. Are these DBAs aware of the adverse effect of missing FKs on the query execution plan?

Comment: I cannot provide a complete example. I suggest that you post a code sample for what you have so far.

Comment: Anyway, you can setup any association you want between an entity's "foreign key" property and another entity's property (or properties) that EF knows as its primary key.

Comment: The database already exists.  I did not design it, nor can I modify it.  The dba's refuse to add foreign keys.

Comment: Does anyone have a link thank shows creating a relation without a foreign key in the database?

Comment: @GertArnold, from my understand, that approach has been attempted and failed many times, unfortunately.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I haven't seen any working example of a one-to-many relation in EF that works without a foreign key constraint defined on the "many" side of the relationship.  I would be interested in seeing an example of one exists!

Comment: Then the attempts were not correct. I have this working in an enterprise system. If you use an edmx, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12609733/861716. With code-first, you can use the regular fluent mapping or data annotations.

Comment: You still did not share with us whether you are using database first approach or code second approach. Which one are you using? If you are using code second approach, simply have your entity classes have the appropriate navigation properties and it should work.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, we are using Code First. I am using the EntityTypeConfiguration.HasMany() method, but how do I tell it which database column I want to act as a foreign key (given that the database does not have a foreign key association between the tables)?

Comment: @pnschofield, it would be a lot easier to help if you provide the relevant code in the question.

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @YacoubMassad.  The article covers the case where you don't want a foreign key *property* on your entity, but not the case where you can't have a foreign key at all in your *database*.

Comment: @pnschofield, if you create navigational properties correctly, it would work, even if you don't have foreign keys in the database.